# Create frozen screen effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, images, photoshop-effects

Is there a way to create this effect in Photoshop?

[image: Windows XP Frozen screen]

I could duplicate the same image over and over again, but that's just wrong. There should be an easier way.

**Edit:** Use of Illustrator and MS Paint is also fine.

Comment: I've tried a few things but I can't find any obvious ways to do this in Photoshop, have you considered using Illustrator?

Comment: Screen shot the pop-up. Then cut, paste, move. You might be able to script that to make it quicker, but I don't see any other way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some fiddling around here's way that might be quicker than copying/pasting/moving.

1. Create your popup.
2. On a separate layer or file, create a black square that is the same size as the popup. Select it and define a new brush (<kbd>Edit > Define Brush Preset</kbd>). You can then discard the black square.
3. Make your canvas fit the final size of the artwork you wish to create (<kbd>Image > Canvas size</kbd>).
4. Using the clone stamp tool, set the sample setting to Current layer, disable the aligned setting. Using your newly defined brush, go on the layer with your popup and precisely sample the popup (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>).
5. Create a new layer and clone your popup as often as you wish, each time you click a new popup will appear (unfortunately you can't just drag it around)

Answer (score 20):

Why use an inferior product when you already have MS Paint installed?

In Paint, use the `Select` tool and select the area you wish to "drag" around. Hold `Shift` and hold down the left mouse button as you drag the selection around, producing the desired effect.

Comment: @Amphiteót Rest easy, for what I was referring to was PS (as a joke): not the Gimp.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was looking for. The best way to do it quickly. But I'll go with [Emilie's answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/40815/28654) since it gives more control. If only it had MS Paint's `SHIFT + drag` combination. I'll also resize the "pattern" that I'm dragging, make it look like it's coming closer to the screen. The image I posted was just a reference to the effect I wanted to do.