# Create " windows trail" effect in vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, illustrator-effects, copy-and-paste

Is there a way to create this effect like in this post but in Adobe Illustrator?

Hold Alt key copy-pasting kind of works, but it is near impossible to lake it look like "window drag" and clone stamp technique does not work with vector object.

[image: Image from this post: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/40813/create-frozen-screen-effect]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the Blend tool for this. In particular, the Replace Spline option.

1. Create your "window", and make it an object
2. Create two instances of that object, anywhere on your illustration
3. Double click the Blend tool, use "Specified Steps", and set this to the total number of windows you want to appear.
4. With the Blend tool selected, click on one instance, then click on the other instance of your object. You should now see a bunch of them in a line.
5. Now comes the magic. Using the Pen tool, draw an open path that you would like the windows to follow. You can use curved lines or straight segments as you see fit.
6. Select both the path and your blended objects, and go to Object > Blend > Replace Spline.

You should now see something like the following:[image]

Modify the parameters to your personal taste!

Comment: I find it better to use specified distance in step 3, "widows" will not look separate when drawing in long distance.